# Z-index: child put behind parent's sibling

Tags: html, css, z-index

I made a navbar with this structure order:

- Floating logo (`z-index: 9`)
- Topmost navbar (`z-index: 8`)
- Sidebar (`z-index: 7`)
- Menu list (`z-index: 6`)
- "Employee List" div (`z-index: -1`)

When I hover each menu on the list, it should show the dropdown menu (which I put as each menu's child). So far it always seen below the "Employee List" div no matter what `z-index` I put on it. Can I make it so the dropdown put above it? Is there anything I can do **other than** putting the dropdown outside the navbar and position it using jquery?

Additionally, I want the dropdown get hidden when I hover things other than the menu list or the dropdown itself.

I'm new in this so please bear with my basic question. Anyone can help me with this? Any help appreciated! :)

```js
$(".burger-btn-wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".main-sidebar").toggleClass("main-sidebar-view");
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 768px; 
}

.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 640px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 8;
}

.navbar-top-left {
  z-index: 999;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {
  z-index: 999; 
}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon i {
  font-size: 10px; 
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 6;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 32px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
} 

.main-sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: -260px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 717px;
  z-index: 7;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper {
  height: 669px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-sidebar-view {
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
   transition: left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-section {
  width: 240px; 
}

.sidebar-section li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-section-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-icon img {
  width: 18px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-sidebar-footer {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  
  .callout {
    right: 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .profile-dropdown-icon {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
  
  

<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="main-sidebar-list-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Organization</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/LZ44Z0dPvtn2OCGT02lwNZuaUK76Zw69uaYSF4sTe63PtTpKS4IiUM7LjsV5VvlH1hsB6bZM4rA8g9fVsYgUzg/192"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Company</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/8pNCxwrs9k-2fnR6iCzgQ-FEhutp_EcFTTfb9jD207NZSwBU98yuTSPZAKwsh7muBJKKG-MBcsgoqbEpXnZLnQ/213"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Employee</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/mE5M0CywlR63kvqGKenpBEdDFYpOnpHB02javJrGr8r0gJGl_-vuUnKJJpWe6pZChsjIq1yXUgofhicw7MvFCw/177"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Termination</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Compensation &amp; Benefits</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/vYgvWe324-eiGFdWDNoBi7WrWHUAFhEbZCoLWve5NE2rBrFrGmK7ZLjW3W0ggCHce1BCyY6FFTzxRm-Fg9VmBA/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Ketenagakerjaan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/bVKXdl3sBeP8-w1wTrEapdUOlcJFSPi4_koRbRVtzL2NR8N-BPZdJUdpPWjSXC13Um6GLbt5DO1DV2t_j7hQDw/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Kesehatan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/TaVNZzoRbkdvziFtWEyv4sEVQMnVVteQt2CB9aCU4xyOdTaCTDAqL9mqUA-3nGmdJZ7qzLZbxXr2xfXjlVDpDg/173"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Payroll</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/NAZCBsbI_bURxMPsr3N05H2_d8KSiz_RtfaMqHp8Tg8tKFEb4RN-5aHgFQiz0y05Ik4BAD8RMRb5LC-Ufg35zA/175"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">PPh 21</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/FNTOwLJTLz1ndzUxgINBH_tCYJgn7rp-HvtVlpTSN1RQ1yuy1q7UskqQikaey0uHl2Fu7C-rXOgaw_VsGH82Lg/136"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">User Management</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/DLaWkbWQ4jxYfEVNpCKBxOyS8G1mzuN24jzbf62tvMsYRvMD0zob2s2K1mBCj62YTYM_MaQmJlt6KmS0WY2uwA/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Master Data</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/h2z5yDkjFcZ5OwhHWcI6VrhUL9Yj-u43QPEjlo7XyHE2pR-ghxrJdXw8mfB5C89AzEd403gqfCrd2JAUMbJ1xQ/199"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Log</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/cn4XSK1tZu9KoSq5Q7iQXAMWcqjw5JolDHCvP52UD2wvu2brkBoit1F7SDUJmFVChGbo1LthZixKzx5ee3jJsQ/156"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Data Migration</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-sidebar-footer">
    &copy; CATAPA 2017
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Memo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download &amp; Upload</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Report</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `overflow: hidden` on the nav bar. The dropdowns are hiding.

```js
$(".burger-btn-wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".main-sidebar").toggleClass("main-sidebar-view");
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 768px; 
}

.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 640px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 8;
}

.navbar-top-left {
  z-index: 999;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {
  z-index: 999; 
}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon i {
  font-size: 10px; 
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 6;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 32px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
} 

.main-sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: -260px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 717px;
  z-index: 7;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper {
  height: 669px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-sidebar-view {
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
   transition: left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-section {
  width: 240px; 
}

.sidebar-section li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-section-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-icon img {
  width: 18px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-sidebar-footer {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  
  .callout {
    right: 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .profile-dropdown-icon {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
  
  

<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="main-sidebar-list-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Organization</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/LZ44Z0dPvtn2OCGT02lwNZuaUK76Zw69uaYSF4sTe63PtTpKS4IiUM7LjsV5VvlH1hsB6bZM4rA8g9fVsYgUzg/192"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Company</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/8pNCxwrs9k-2fnR6iCzgQ-FEhutp_EcFTTfb9jD207NZSwBU98yuTSPZAKwsh7muBJKKG-MBcsgoqbEpXnZLnQ/213"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Employee</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/mE5M0CywlR63kvqGKenpBEdDFYpOnpHB02javJrGr8r0gJGl_-vuUnKJJpWe6pZChsjIq1yXUgofhicw7MvFCw/177"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Termination</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Compensation &amp; Benefits</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/vYgvWe324-eiGFdWDNoBi7WrWHUAFhEbZCoLWve5NE2rBrFrGmK7ZLjW3W0ggCHce1BCyY6FFTzxRm-Fg9VmBA/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Ketenagakerjaan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/bVKXdl3sBeP8-w1wTrEapdUOlcJFSPi4_koRbRVtzL2NR8N-BPZdJUdpPWjSXC13Um6GLbt5DO1DV2t_j7hQDw/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Kesehatan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/TaVNZzoRbkdvziFtWEyv4sEVQMnVVteQt2CB9aCU4xyOdTaCTDAqL9mqUA-3nGmdJZ7qzLZbxXr2xfXjlVDpDg/173"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Payroll</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/NAZCBsbI_bURxMPsr3N05H2_d8KSiz_RtfaMqHp8Tg8tKFEb4RN-5aHgFQiz0y05Ik4BAD8RMRb5LC-Ufg35zA/175"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">PPh 21</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/FNTOwLJTLz1ndzUxgINBH_tCYJgn7rp-HvtVlpTSN1RQ1yuy1q7UskqQikaey0uHl2Fu7C-rXOgaw_VsGH82Lg/136"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">User Management</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/DLaWkbWQ4jxYfEVNpCKBxOyS8G1mzuN24jzbf62tvMsYRvMD0zob2s2K1mBCj62YTYM_MaQmJlt6KmS0WY2uwA/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Master Data</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/h2z5yDkjFcZ5OwhHWcI6VrhUL9Yj-u43QPEjlo7XyHE2pR-ghxrJdXw8mfB5C89AzEd403gqfCrd2JAUMbJ1xQ/199"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Log</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/cn4XSK1tZu9KoSq5Q7iQXAMWcqjw5JolDHCvP52UD2wvu2brkBoit1F7SDUJmFVChGbo1LthZixKzx5ee3jJsQ/156"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Data Migration</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-sidebar-footer">
    &copy; CATAPA 2017
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Memo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download &amp; Upload</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Report</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried removing only the overflow-y, since I need it to be able to be scrolled in x direction, but it doesn't work

Comment: We still need to scroll down the menu list to see the rest of dropdown. Why is this happening?